# Missing email replies

Tags: civimail, email, sparkpost

We are using CiviCRM 15.4 on Drupal 7.

We are using the Sparkpost extension to send bulk emails through sparkpost.

This all works great, we get nice mail tracking and reports.

My users also want to send emails "from" their personal email accounts (running on outlook online) and allow email recipients to reply-to. the same email.

Again, this has been set up for a while and working great.

Recently, however, someone or something enabled the setting: `Track replies using VERP in Reply-To header`.

As a result, the default reply-to was replaced with a tracking address which when replied to appears to be sending the emails to a location unknown...

I have disabled the VERP but my users want the emails sent to them in the interim. Is there any way to retrieve them? the VERP reply-to doesn't bounce when mailed so they are going somewhere...

I do not know exactly when this occurred as there is no bounce record or error when you email one of those tracking addresses so it only became clear when a user expecting replies got none.